# Change slider minimum value and maximum value of Ramotion/Fluid

Tags: swift, user-interface

I am using Fluid Slider Library in Swift.
https://github.com/Ramotion/fluid-slider

How can i change the slider minimum value default 0 to another?
I am changing the minimum and maximum label attributed text but I am unable to change the default minimum fraction value that starts from 0 and the maximum value of fraction

[image]

Comment: Post the code which you've implemented. So that we can find a proper solution as per your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The *fraction* variable goes from 0 to 1, so just add the minimum value to the multiplication. Example:

```
let string = formatter.string(from: ((fraction * 20) + 30) as NSNumber) ?? ""
```

Where `30` is my min val and `(fraction * 20) + 30` is my max